# Search a video of a playlist in youtube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have this as a request for youtube api in displaying videos of a particular video playlist **https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId='+playlist_id+'&key={My Key}**

**The Problem**
How will I able to have a request that will search a video in that particular video playlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the video id and have it return just that video.

> [videoId  string](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) 
>   The videoId parameter specifies that the request should
>   return only the playlist items that contain the specified video.

If the question is how do I return only the "dog" videos in the playlist, the answer is you cant.   There is no free text searching in [playlistitems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)

Comment: How will I implement to return only dog videos in playlist then? Please help.

Comment: Fetch the full list from Google, then sort though them in your application.

Comment: Run the request above "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId='+playlist_id+'&key={My Key} "   when they results are returned to you from google into your application go though them one by one and check if its a dog video or not.